# Removing a comma from a file produced by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a file with one name per line. I made a list using:

```
names = [('a', '1\n'), ('b', '2\n'), ('c', '3\n'), ('d', '4\n')]

names = list(itertools.chain(*names))
```

this is the result:

```
['a', '1\n', 'b', '2\n', 'c', '3\n', 'd', '4\n']
```

After this i've done:

```
separated_names = ', '.join(names)
```

to remove the strings from the list, and the result is:

```
'a', '1'

, 'b', '2'

, 'c', '3'

, 'd', '4'
```

The problem is the comma that starts each line. The output that I need is in the form:

```
'a', '1'

'b', '2'

'c', '3'

'd', '4'
```

Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
names = [('a', '1\n'), ('b', '2\n'), ('c', '3\n'), ('d', '4\n')]

archive_out = open("output.txt", 'w')

for line in names:
    archive_out.write(str(", ".join(line)))

archive_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> names = [('a', '1\n'), ('b', '2\n'), ('c', '3\n'), ('d', '4\n')]
>>> print(''.join('%s, %s' % line for line in names))
a, 1
b, 2
c, 3
d, 4
```

On the other hand, if you really wanted the single quotes to appear in the output:

```
>>> print('\n'.join("'%s', '%s'" % (a, b.strip()) for a, b in names))
'a', '1'
'b', '2'
'c', '3'
'd', '4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is a mapping between one thing and another, so you should use a dictionary:

```
names = {'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3', 'd': '4'}
```

Then you can iterate over the dictionary's items to write to the file:

```
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for key, value in names.items():
        f.write('{}, {}'.format(key, value))
```